# Reward Point Expiry Warning Email sending every hour - Magento 2 EE

Tags: reward-points

I am working on Magento 2 EE/ Adobe Commerce 2.4.3.p1. We have configured Reward Point System for users. But from a week now, magento is sending Reward point Expiry warning email every hour. We disabled it for now. Please help.

Comment: I am guessing you are using some third-party extension for this one? if yes then check the admin configuration of this extension I am not sure but maybe you will find some configuration for the expiry time or expiry email